# View doesn't update in ionic while using tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using web sockets for my real-time application. Everything works fine. But recently I got stuck in an issue. I've 3 tabs in the bottom, and when I switch to one of these three tabs, I've 2 sub tabs in its view. In this View, I'm not able to update my content on socket broadcast.

I can see the socket broadcast from the server, but the content does not update, until I switch tab or pull the ion-content down to refresh.

I tried $apply/safeApply and $timeout but nothing worked. But if I recall/reload my current view, it updates, but that doesn't look good to me, because it gives a white flash.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of ways to Solve this Issue ...

Best way is implemented in this link

http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/Djfdo

set **cache-view="false"**

You Have to Set Your View like

```
<ion-view  cache-view="false">
```

Another Solution

Every time entering to your View you can reload the data

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.enter", function(event, data){
   // Load Your Data

});
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I want my view to be updated without any view change, as soon as I receive socket broadcast, I try to update my view, where it fails. Every where else in my app, it is working fine, but I guess due to some tabs issue it is not working.

Comment: Did You Try Second Solution

Comment: I'm already doing this. And it loads the content initially nicely. But once it is loaded, and if the next time I change something from the web-app, socket event is broadcasted, and I update it in my mobile app (which fails).

Comment: please Use ng-click and redirect through $state instead of href ....   and also check your console there might be an error ... Which can stop the reloading

Comment: Hi Please Use $ionicTabsDelegate.select(2, true)

Comment: Use the ionicView.beforeEnter rather than enter

Answer (score 0):

Probably has to do with the view being cached. See the [documentation on ion-nav-view](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/) (scroll down a bit to the "caching" part) on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

HI Muhammad Mehdi Raza,

In Tabs url is given as hyperlink (href) instead og giving hyperlink use click event on tab and write function in controller and use $state.go method to navigate to the particular this will reload the page when click on the particular tab